# Why is localhost App 301ing HTTP to HTTPS?

Tags: apache, redirect, https

I have a WP site running locally that has suddenly stopped functioning properly.
The following 2 lines from the Apache log show when the problem started occurring. I had made no configuration changes I am aware of in that timeframe.

**::1 – – [16/Jan/2020:13:46:33 +0000] “GET /chfootball/wp-content/themes/oceanwp-child/assets/css/frontpage.css?ver1.3 HTTP/1.1” 200 7368**

**::1 – – [17/Jan/2020:11:53:38 +0000] “GET /chfootball/wp-content/themes/oceanwp-child/assets/css/frontpage.css?ver1.3 HTTP/1.1” 301 384**

On inspecting the site on the Console tab, I see the following:

**Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
/chfootball/wp-content/themes/oceanwp-child/assets/css/frontpage.css?ver1.3:1**

When I hover over the file name, it is prefixed by **https://localhost/**

As this is a local development system, there is no SSL certificate present.
Both home and siteurl in wp_options are set to http://localhost/chfootball

I have looked at my .htaccess, httpd.conf, and httpd-vhosts.conf files and can find nothing relating to https or 301 redirects.

Typing the resource into a url also does not work as http is replaced with https and so the resource is not displayed.

**http://localhost/devproject/wp-content/themes/oceanwp-child/assets/css/frontpage.css**

When I inspect what is going on in the Network traffic tab and save the results into a HAR file, I found the following. I've just entered the lines I think are important. This is the route of the problem but I don't know what is causing it and how to fix it. I am assuming that Apache is doing this and so any advice would be most welcome.

```
      "request": {
          "method": "GET",
          "url": "http://localhost/chfootball/wp-content/themes/oceanwp-child/assets/css/frontpage.css?ver1.3",
          "httpVersion": "HTTP/1.1",
..................................................................................................................................
        "response": {
          "status": 301,
          "statusText": "Moved Permanently",
          "httpVersion": "HTTP/1.1",
..................................................................................................................................
           "name": "Location",
            "value": "https://localhost/chfootball/wp-content/themes/oceanwp-child/assets/css/frontpage.css?ver1.3"
```

Comment: If there is nothing in .htaccess or .conf files, then your app is doing it.

Comment: I've checked the app and there is no reference to https in it. All the paths are relative and so should feed off http://localhost/chfootball.

Comment: Also, will the app be running when I try and access the resource through a url?